# Javascript how to Toggle button background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can some one tell me how to Toggle button background color on click?

look at this buttons and add examples please : http://jsfiddle.net/ukkj7dth/

```
<div class="button">button 1</div>
<div class="button">button 2</div>
<div class="button">button 3</div>
<div class="button">button 4</div>
<div class="button">button 5</div>
<div class="button">button 6</div>
```

i want it to be like, when a button 1 clicked it must change background color to yellow and when button 2 clicked then button 1 must go back to green background and button 2 change to yellow etc...

Thanks

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ukkj7dth/3/

Comment: It seems you haven't even tried anything. Where is the JavaScript / jQuery part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just toggle a class

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('myClass').siblings().removeClass('myClass');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukkj7dth/5/)

Comment: sir, it works when i click on button 1 it will change to yellow but when i click on button 2 it will change to yellow too but button 1 will still be on yellow. i need it to be changed again to green when other button clicked

Comment: @wes112 - and it does that now

Comment: sir it wirked but do i need some js file in that? because it's working on jsfiddle but not working on my page. if there's some js file please send me it's link